# getting timer to stop w/js or jq

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, countdown, countdowntimer

I'm trying to get my clock to stop at zero and then show results pg. But for now I am unable to get it to stop.

```
var clock = {
time: 2,
timeleft: 0,
bigben: null,

countDown: function() {
    clock.time--;
    $("#timer").html(clock.time);
},
start: function() {
    bigben = setInterval(clock.countDown, 1000);
},
stop: function() {
    // clearInterval(intervalId);
    if (time == timeleft) {
        window.clearInterval(bigben);
        // Display countdown
        $('#timer').html(time + "seconds");
        time--
    }
    //end of timer
   if (time === timeleft) {
        window.clearInterval(bigben);
        gameOver();
    };
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout function. This fonction play his callback when time is at 0.

```
setTimeout (function () { your code; }, 1000);
```

1000 is the time in milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

I did not see anywhere you call the stop function.
add `clock.stop` in your countdown function.
and it seems that in your stop block, the "time", "timeleft" and "bigben" variables are all not reachable....
You need to use clock.time, clock.timeleft, clock.bigben instead.

Try below.

```
var clock = {
time: 2,
timeleft: 0,
bigben: null,

countDown: function() {
    clock.time--;
    $("#timer").html(clock.time);
    clock.stop();
},
start: function() {
    clock.bigben = setInterval(clock.countDown, 1000);
},
stop: function() {

    if (clock.time > clock.timeleft) {

        $('#timer').html(clock.time + "seconds");

    }

   if (clock.time === clock.timeleft) {
        window.clearInterval(clock.bigben);
        //gameOver();
    }
}
};
clock.start();
```

I commented out the gameOver() call, since there is no definition of that function within current code.